# XSLT 1.0 Remove leading zeros and add decimal point to a value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm working with XSLT 1.0 and trying to remove all leading zeros and add a decimal point before the last 2 numbers.  The number of characters will always be the same.

Examples:

- 0001094125 needs to translate to 10941.25
- 0000042000 needs to translate to 420.00
- 0000040458 needs to translate to 404.58
- 0000153800 needs to translate to 1538.00

I read using format-number() is an option, but I don't want any rounding to take place.  Any ideas how to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `format-number()` without rounding...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <test>0001094125</test>
    <test>0000042000</test>
    <test>0000040458</test>
    <test>0000153800</test>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(normalize-space() div 100,'#.00')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <test>10941.25</test>
   <test>420.00</test>
   <test>404.58</test>
   <test>1538.00</test>
</doc>
```

Working fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBu8/1

Alternatively, you could format the number to remove the leading zeros and then you could use substring() to concat the first part of the string, a decimal point, and the last part of the string (based on string length).

Example...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="nbr" select="format-number(normalize-space(),'#')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length($nbr)"/>
      <xsl:value-of 
        select="concat(substring($nbr,1,$length - 2),'.',substring($nbr, $length - 1))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <test>10941.25</test>
   <test>420.00</test>
   <test>404.58</test>
   <test>1538.00</test>
</doc>
```

Working fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBu8